# pop up window removes primary node in javafx

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-2, javafx-8, scenebuilder

I want to create a photo gallery in javafx using pop up window .
But when I pass target image to a method to set content of a pop up window to that image primary image will be removed and pop up window will be open.Why?Please help me .Thank's
 ( Excuse my for my bad English!!! )

This is that snippet code .

```
        final Popup popup = new Popup();
        popup.getContent().add(image);
        popup.setOnShown(new EventHandler<WindowEvent>(){
         @Override
         public void handle(WindowEvent t) {
             image.setFitHeight(400);
             image.setFitWidth(400);

         }
    });

       popup.show(stage);
```

Comment: `image` is an `ImageView` that is displayed on your main stage?

Comment: Yes,this is an ImageView.

Comment: Not quite sure I understand the issue, is the image already displayed on the "main" stage? And it disappears from there?

Comment: When user clicks on the Image to show it larger that image will disappear from the main stage and that image is shown in a pop up windows and when the pop up window close it doesn't appear again.I want to the main image doesn't never disappear .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your image is an ImageView, which is a Node. No node can appear in two scenes, or twice in the same scene graph.

To fix this, create a new ImageView, using the same image displayed in the current image (Images may be reused, even though ImageViews may not).

```
    final Popup popup = new Popup();
    final ImageView popupImage = new ImageView(image.getImage());
    popup.getContent().add(popupImage);
    popup.setOnShown(new EventHandler<WindowEvent>(){
     @Override
     public void handle(WindowEvent t) {
         popupImage.setFitHeight(400);
         popupImage.setFitWidth(400);

     }
});

   popup.show(stage);
```