# how to repeat a node in same scene in javafx

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-2, javafx-8

I want to repeat one node in scene .
Is it possible ?
for example I have an anchorpane and 3 panes on it . 
I have one button on pane(1) and I want to add it to pane(2) after some process in program ... .
I want to repeat that node exactly like the old one( with same properties)

Comment: Can't you just bind the properties?

Comment: I want all properties ... Is it possible to bind "all" properties ? I just want to show a snapshot of that node in a different pane . (of course a real snapshot that user can interact with it !)

Comment: There's no shortcut, you would just have to bind the properties of interest, one at a time. (And you don't want to bind *all* properties; for example you certainly wouldn't want the `parentProperty` of the two nodes to be equal...) Perhaps it would help if you could explain why you actually want to do this.

Comment: I should do it for a user-onboarding process...because I need a separate layout for onboarding and without changes in controller of main application...just can use fxml of main app ...I wanted to just enable special node in each step...I tried many solutions...and in this solution I want to add a transparent layout and generate special node on it so user just can interact with special node in each step ...

Answer (score 4):

No, you cannot repeat the same node in a scene.

From the [Node Javadocs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Node.html) :

> A node may occur at most once anywhere in the scene graph. Specifically, a node must appear no more than once in all of the following: as the root node of a Scene, the children ObservableList of a Parent, or as the clip of a Node.

Answering your question :

> I want to repeat that node exactly like the old one

To achieve this, create a `styleclass` and `add it to similar nodes` that you want to create.

Comment: so there isn't any solution like this ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22691243/pop-up-window-removes-primary-node-in-javafx/22692421#22692421....And I need to keep all properties like layoutx, prefwidth and ...so I can't to it with css only

Comment: You can create a custom control with the `properties` and use it by creating a new object of the control everytime.

Comment: can you give one example please?

Answer (score 0):

Only one Node appears on the scene graph, if you want to have same scene manipulating several times on the scene, then you gona have to try the hard way by creating other nodes with similar content like the one you want to repeat on the scene graph. Adding them to the scene will look like the same Node on the scene.

I don't other way of doing it,more answers and corrections are welcome. Sorry to respond to this old qtn