# Cannot use Node in two different scenes.

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-2

I am making a record storing app with graphics. I had to make the root node of the scene static in order for an animated class to interact with it. So now I got that part working but by making that node static I am now encountering an IllegalArgumentException for using the same node in two different scenes. This only happens when the scene is created a second time.

I've seen this: [how to repeat a node in same scene in javafx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31102899/how-to-repeat-a-node-in-same-scene-in-javafx)

I'm just looking for help on the code. Or some ideas on where to place the root node or possibly a method that could get me a new vbox with all the necessary elements inside;
Thank YOU!

```
class AddButtonRecordHandler implements EventHandler<ActionEvent>{

private static VBox vbox = new VBox();

 public void handle(ActionEvent e){
    vbox.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
    vbox.getChildren().addAll(hb,new AllSphere(30));  
    Stage addRecordDialog = new Stage(); 
    Scene scene = new Scene(vbox, fieldSize(), 200);
    addRecordDialog.setScene(scene);
    addRecordDialog.show();

  public static void newAllSphere(){
    vbox.getChildren().remove(1);
    vbox.getChildren().add(new AllSphere(30)); 

 }
}


final class AllSphere extends Sphere{

   Material material;
   SequentialTransition st = new SequentialTransition();
   private TranslateTransition moveAway = new TranslateTransition(Duration.millis(300),this);

    public AllSphere(double radius){ 

    moveAway.setOnFinished(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
          public void handle(ActionEvent e){
             AddButtonRecordHandler.newAllSphere();
          }
      });
  }

    public void moveAway(){

        st.jumpTo(Duration.ZERO);
        moveAway.setByX(800);
        moveAway.setCycleCount(1);
        moveAway.play();

    }
```

Comment: Move the `VBox` declaration+initialisation to the `handle` method and pass `vbox` as parameter to the `newAllSphere` method.

Comment: "I had to make the root node of the scene static in order for an animated class to interact with it." It's not clear why you think this, or what problem you are trying to solve by making this static, but static means that it "belongs to the class" (as opposed to "belongs to instances of the class"). It has nothing at all to do with being able to access something or interact with it in any way.

Comment: Sorry, I got it figured out. An animation I had was supposed to update the Vbox from another class. That worked fine until the scene was loaded again with the handle() and the same static vbox was used giving an exception. I simply said if the scene is loaded more than once create a new vbox and add everything to it....