# duplicate children added error for a class that implements hashCode()

Tags: java, observablecollection, javafx-11

I have a Point class that extends Circle. I'm doing this to add the equals and hashCode  methods so that I can add the instances to a Set without duplicates in the set.

The problem I'm having is that when I try to add 2 points with the same coordinates to the pane, I get an error of duplicate children. I did some investigation on my code and found that it is connected with the hashCode. If I comment out the hasCode method in the Point class it works.

I need to be able to add **all** the points to the pane but only non duplicates to the set.

Here is the code.

```
package my.convexHull;

import java.util.Objects;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.shape.Circle;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

/**
 *
 * @author sgordon
 */
public class ConvexHull extends Application {

    final static double RADIUS = 3;
    ObservableList<Node> points;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        // Create pane for the piints
        Pane pointsPane = new Pane();
        points = pointsPane.getChildren();

        double p[][] = {
            {30.0, 248.0},
            {114.0, 215.0},
            {114.0, 215.0},
            {114.0, 215.0}
        };
        points.clear();
        for (int i = 0; i < p.length; i++) {
            points.add(new Point(p[i][0], p[i][1], RADIUS));
        }

        Pane linePane = new Pane();
        Pane convexHull = new StackPane(pointsPane, linePane);

        BorderPane root = new BorderPane();

        //Creating a scene object 
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 430, 330);
        //Setting title to the Stage 
        stage.setTitle("Convex Hull");

        //Adding scene to the stage 
        stage.setScene(scene);

        //Displaying the contents of the stage 
        stage.show();

        root.setCenter(convexHull);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Application.launch(args);
    }

    class Point extends Circle {

        public Point() {
            super();
        }

        public Point(double x, double y, double radius) {
            super(x, y, radius);
        }

        @Override
        public int hashCode() {
            return Objects.hash(getCenterX(), getCenterY());
        }

        @Override
        public boolean equals(Object obj) {
            if (this == obj) {
                return true;
            }
            if (!(obj instanceof Point)) {
                return false;
            }

            return getCenterX() == ((Point) obj).getCenterX() && getCenterY() == ((Point) obj).getCenterY();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Without seeing your whole application, I think it's a mistake to use the same class for the data you are managing (the set of points) and the representation of that data in the UI. I would think about removing equals/hashCode from `Point`, and creating a new class (`PointData`, say) which manages the identity of the points. `Point` can take a `PointData` as a constructor parameter. (Having said that it isn't clear to me why your display should include points you've discarded from your set)

Comment: Your paste just adds points to a list. hashCode doesn't mean 'it magically deduplicates!' - you'd have to put them in e.g. a HashSet, which doesn't allow duplicates.

Comment: @rzwitserloot This a barebones version of my application. I'm adding it to a TreeSet later in my app.  I'm just trying to show that it won't let me add a duplicate point to the pane. What I'm trying to do is a ConvexHull so the points are displayed but there is only a small amount of points that create the convex.

Comment: @tgdavies I already have a double array that are the points I'm creating the Point class specifically to be able to add them to the pane.

Comment: You could remove hashCode and equals from Point, and then use a custom Comparator in your TreeSet.

Comment: My guess is that you have overwritten the `Nodes'` (In this case, `Circles`) methods to determine if `Nodes` are equal. In JavaFX, you can only add a `Node` to a `Scene` once. My guess is that your app is now seeing `Nodes` that are equal by your new standard as the same `Node.   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31102899/how-to-repeat-a-node-in-same-scene-in-javafx#:~:text=No%2C%20you%20cannot%20repeat%20the,the%20clip%20of%20a%20Node.

Answer (score 0):

Ah, `TreeSet`. See, this is why you need to paste self-contained examples - code that, on its own, shows the error.

TreeSet **does not use hashcode AT ALL**.

TreeSet solely use the `compare` feature. That one is evidently broken. Fix it to be consistent, and your problems will go away.

Comment: I do not think this explains why even in the example without `TreeSet`, the OP is still experiencing the same issue.